# pattern matching an array, not their elements per se

Tags: php, parsing, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a way of pattern matching the "geometry" of an array, the order in which the elements appear, not the contents of each element directly.

Let me outline what I mean by some examples. Given the target array:

```
array('T_STRING','T_VARIABLE','ASSIGN','T_STRING','LPAREN','T_VARIABLE','COMMA','T_VARIABLE','RPAREN');
//as a matter of fact, these would be the tokens for the PHP code "foo $var = Foo($arg1,$arg2)'
```

Then the following "pattern" would match, **returning the 0-based indexes of the matches, as well as the indexes of the groupings**, just like preg_match_all() would do for strings:

```
array('T_STRING', '?', '(', 'T_VARIABLE', 'ASSIGN' ')', '?',
    'T_STRING', 'LPAREN', '(', 'T_VARIABLE', 'COMMA', '?', ')', '?', 'RPAREN');
```

This is only a simplified PoC, the way I intend to use it is much more complicated, and I don't want to use the full parser generator from PEAR (the lemon port to PHP), which would be overkill.

Are you aware of a function (possibly not an internal PHP function) or project which does just that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever I hear "pattern matching" I think "regex".

Push that array to a string and match against the pattern you're looking for using regex.  You may be able to a symbol replacement to make the regex small and manageable:

Your array above could be reduced to a string like this:

```
$arrayPattern = 'SVASL_PVCVR_P'
```

Now you can use RegEx to match against it.

```
if (preg_match('/VA/', $arrayPattern)) 
  print "You've got a Variable followed by an Assign!";
```

Just a thought....

Comment: Certainly something I've already thought about, but how about the part
"returning the 0-based indexes of the matches, as well as the indexes of the groupings" which I didn't write in bold text by mistake? ...

Comment: As you may know, if you're going to use regexp, the third param in `preg_match($expression, $content, $matches)` can give return the matched components.  You may have to do some extra work from there, but it should give you a decent foot hold.  However, in the long run, I'm not sure if regexp is the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are you looking for Code Analysis, then these [slides of Sebastian Bergmann](http://tinyurl.com/y8grgqu) might be of use to you. Starting with slide 17 is examples for analysis by tokens.

Comment: Weird. It's the correct URL. I wrapped into a tiny URL and it should be working now. Does it?