# Get position of all matches in group

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Consider the following example:

```
$target = 'Xa,a,aX';
$pattern = '/X((a),?)*X/';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern,$target,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

What it does is returning only the last 'a' in the series, but what I need is all the 'a's.

Particularly, I need the position of <s>ALL</s> **EACH OF** the 'a's inside the string **separately**, thus PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE.

The example is much more complex, see the related question: [pattern matching an array, not their elements per se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799419/pattern-matching-an-array-not-their-elements-per-se)

Thanks

Comment: If this description is not a good representation of your actual problem, why start this new post at all?

Comment: It is simplified, it's another "sub-problem" of my complex problem, and it can be seen as a standalone problem, with its own solution.

Comment: Can the target contain multiple lists of a's, eg: 'abcdXa,a,a,aXefghiXa,a,a,a,a,a,a,aX'? If so, do you want two separate arrays in this case, one for each list of a's, or one combined array containing the indexes of all the a's regardless of where they came from?

Comment: No, there is only one pair of X, no nesting or whatever. I need each position at which an a can be found within the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It groups a single match since the regex `X((a),?)*X` matches the entire string. The last `((a),?)` will be grouped.

What you want to match is an `a` that has an `X` before it (and the start of the string), has a comma ahead of it, or has an `X` ahead of it (and the end of the string).

```
$target = 'Xa,a,aX';
$pattern = '/(?<=^X)a|a(?=X$|,)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $target, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your regex includes X, it matches once. It finds one large match with groups in it. What you want is many matches, each with its own position.

So, in my opinion the best you can do is simply search for /a/ or /a,?/ without any X. Then matches[0] will contain all appearances of 'a'

If you need them between X, pre-select this part of the string.